# A Common constructor in Python

Tags: python, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign function arguments to `self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682848/assign-function-arguments-to-self)

Often I have constructors that look like the following:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self,a,b,c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
```

I was wondering if there was a convenient way to encode constructors like this. Perhaps something that looks like:

```
class Foo(object):
  SOME_MACRO_LIKE_THINGY_THAT_SPECIFIES_THE_CONSTRUCTOR(a,b,c)
```

that would behave exactly like the original code above.

What bugs me with the original version is that I have to write each instance variable of Foo three times (once as an argument, once as self.a and once again as the value to assign to self.a).

I suppose it's not that big a deal, but I feel like the code would look neater with less repetition.

What is the Pythonic way to handle this situation?

Comment: Frankly I like the original/normal/standard way. I see it dozens of times everyday. I know exactly how it works and what it does. This is a place IMO where an extra abstraction will detract greatly from the readability of your code. Now I have to go dig up your macro thingy that may jump through python magic to do amazing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird, but you could use `__slots__` to achieve this:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        for k,v in zip(self.__slots__, args):
            setattr(self, k, v)

        for k,v in kw.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

class ChildA(Base):
    __slots__ = 'a', 'b', 'c'

class ChildB(Base):
    __slots__ = 'x', 'y', 'z'
```

You could also use the following technique to save yourself some typing when initializing classes with lots of arguments:

```
def autoargs(l):
    self = l.pop('self')
    for k,v in l.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        autoargs(locals())
```

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Flashback: the `autoargs` snippet is from [O'Reilly's Python Cookbook, Second Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007973.do) - great book that's still surprisingly relevant, given that it covers Python 2.3 and 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

you could make `Foo` and all others as subclasses of a master Class, ie,

```
class MasterObject(object):
  def __init__(self,a,b,c):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c


class Foo(MasterObject):
  def __init__(self,a,b,c):
    MasterObject.__init__(a,b,c)
```

Comment: Or even use `**kwargs` and `setattr`... Oh, this makes me sad.

Comment: true, this could certainly be made even more general, but the concept is still the same

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)
        del self.__dict__["self"]
```

but then you have to name all the instance variables every time you instantiate the class. I think this makes the code more fragile. Since most people don't like fragile code, they stick with the explicit version.

You could write a macro for your editor to expand them I suppose, but I don't think a very large percentage of time is spent on that detail, and not all classes want to save all the arguments into the instance.