# how can i make **kwargs as self variable

Tags: python-2.7, keyword-argument

I made my own class for some data processing.

Here is my concept of class module condition

1. I want to take all user input variables including `**kwargs` from `__init__` only
2. `__init__` doing pre processing which need `**kwargs` for one of the input variables
3. also need additional data processing function inside of class which need `**kwargs`
4. also need `__call__` method which need `**kwargs`

to satisfy all my conditions, in my view I need to make `**kwargs` as something like `self.**kwargs`.  So, how can I make keyword arguments to self variables?

Comment: Keyword arguments are a syntax feature mostly, while you are talking about actual data handling. This probably doesn't make sense. Anyhow, your question is unclear to me. In order to improve it, I suggest you provide example code how you would do it without making `kwargs` a member, just for comparison.

Comment: 1) you can just pass `**kwargs` to the according function call 2) if required you may create a local `dict( **kwargs)` 3) don't use `kwargs` if not really necessary. An explicit list of arguments is by far more readable and more easy considering code documentation.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `**foo` in the parameters of a function, `foo` is passed to the function as a perfectly ordinary `dict`.  If you want to save that `dict`, just copy it to a member variable:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs) :
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def function():
        if 'Arg1' in self.kwargs:
            return self.kwargs['Arg1']
        else
            return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685206/7762936