# Is it possible to set attributes of a class while creating an instance without constructor?

Tags: python

In Python, if I have a `class` like

```
class Rectangle:
   x:int = 0
   y:int = 0
   width:int = 0
   height:int = 0
```

Is there a way to create an instance of it *and* setting all attributes all at once without a constructor?

Something like (obviously not working) :

```
rect = Reactangle() { x = 0, y = 0, width = 20, height = 30 }
```

I am aware of dictionaries, so I'm open to suggestions.

### Edit

I am aware that I could do

```
class Rectangle:
  def __init__(x:int = 0, y:int = 0, width:int = 0, height:int = 0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
```

But that's not really a nice looking solution, with all the repetitions, when the class contains a dozen attributes, etc.

As read in the comments, it looks like [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) is the way to go.

Comment: Reading between the lines, you may be looking for dataclasses: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: That last line is essentially a call to a constructor. Why avoid a constructor call?

Comment: Also note that how you have your class defined, those are class attributes, not instance attributes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are data classes and how are they different from common classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes)

Comment: I don't understand.  You want to initialize an object but not use `__init__`?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682848/assign-function-arguments-to-self

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to call a constructor, or you don't want to need to manually write a constructor?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I was trying to avoid "modifying the attribute of an instance while instanciating a class". That's silly formulation, don't be pedantic :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a class that uses `__init__` would do what you want (it's a little unclear).  Note that you've defined a class with class variables only.  Something like this is more typical:

```
class Rectangle:
   def __init__(self, x:int=0, y:int=0, width:int=0, height:int=0):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.width = width
       self.height = height


# instantiation:
rect = Rectangle() # uses defaults

rect = Rectangle(x=1,y=2,width=3,height=4) # create instance and set attributes as you say
```

This is pretty vanilla.  Alternatives include the `attrs` library or a `dataclass`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware about that, but I provided a simple example. My actual class has many attributes and it's silly to duplicate all of them in the constructor. I would prefer declaring the class attribute and then overriding them directly without arguments. (I have updated the question to explain this)