# Python OOP Auto Assigning Keyword Arguments

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

I am new to programming and I came across this piece of code in the following thread:
[Assign function arguments to `self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682848/assign-function-arguments-to-self)

```
class C(object):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
             self.__dict__ = dict(kwargs)
c = C(g="a",e="b",f="c")
print(c.g,c.e,c.f)

Output:
a b c
```

This would allow inputting any number of keyword arguments and assign them to attributes accordingly.

My questions are:

1. Why does it work? What does `self.__dict__` do here?
2. Is there any other usage of `self.__dict__`?

I would also appreciate any kind of resources that could help me understand it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19907498/764182

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the \_\_dict\_\_.\_\_dict\_\_ attribute of a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877290/what-is-the-dict-dict-attribute-of-a-python-class)

Answer (score 0):

```
Here **kwargs represent one can take any number of parameters.  
    
c = C(g="a",e="b",f="c") means that:  
variable g = "a" 
variable e = "b" 
variable f = "c"
    
Here self.__ dict __ contains the dictionary as: {g: "a", e: "b", f:"c"}

  __ dict __ is A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.  

  Or speaking in simple words every object in python has an attribute which is denoted by __ dict __.  
   
 And this object contains all attributes defined for the object. __ dict __ is also called mappingproxy object.
```

Answer (score 0):

self.**dict**  is a dictionary which contains key value pairs of a particular object and its attributes.It is generally used for listing out all the attributes and its values of a particular object.

In  this example self.**dict** is {g:"a",e:"b",f:"c"}

**kwargs is used when we don't know how many keyword arguments are given when the object is created.So,converting kwargs into a dictionary and assigning it to the self.**dict** is same as creating all the attributes and setting their values.